# How to use transition in CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: objective-c, caanimation

I want to show a few images using `CAKeyframeAnimation`, how can I perform `transitions` between images? Or how can I add `CATransition` to the `animation`? Such as: image1 eases out then image2 eases in, image2 fades out then image3 fades in, etc

Comment: May be this link will be helpful to you, https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One layer for one image works good. I can add animation at the begin/end of every layer to show in/out transition.

Answer (score 3):

**CAKeyframeAnimation :**

```
- (void)animateImages
{
    CAKeyframeAnimation *keyframeAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    keyframeAnimation.values = self.imagesArray;

    keyframeAnimation.repeatCount = 1.0f;
    keyframeAnimation.duration = kAnimationDuration; // static const with your value

    keyframeAnimation.delegate = self;

    keyframeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    keyframeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

    CALayer *layer = self.animationImageView.layer;

    [layer addAnimation:keyframeAnimation
                 forKey:@"girlAnimation"];
}
```

Comment: I'd like to make transitions between images, such as: image1 ease out then image2 ease in, image2 fade out then image3 fade in, etc